# Extract content within a div from a web page within an Android app

Tags: android, html, web

I have a web page of my kid's school
https://sites.google.com/a/hareut.tzafonet.org.il/a3_2014/home/hwdwt-hmwrh

I want to create an app that will show the teacher's announcements, and by clicking on them will open a link.

First of all: how do I get the announcements from the site?
If I am looking into the page's source, I see that before each announcement, there is a line:

```
div class="announcement"
```

and then on the next line there is the announcement with its link.

So, how can I get them from the page?